# catch block doesn't get fired when API returns any error

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am making a normal API call, but for some reason I don't see `console.log(err)` in my catch block
when I get 500 error. It always fires `console.log(result)` in my then block
What am I doing wrong?

```
const startHandler = () => {
    setOpenLoadingModal(true);
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: headers,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(" ~ file: index.js ~ line 159 ~ .then ~ result", result)
        const { client_id, token } = result;
        if (!token || !client_id){
          setOpenErrorModal(true);
          return setOpenLoadingModal(false);
        } else{
          return history.push({
            pathname: FORMS_URL.LANDING_PAGE,
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)

        setOpenErrorModal(true);
        setOpenLoadingModal(false);
      });
  };
```

Comment: can you check in developer tools / network tab and attach the response for 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` doesn't reject on 4xx/5xx error status

[Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> The Promise returned from `fetch()` **won’t reject on HTTP error status**
> even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, as soon as the
> server responds with headers, the Promise will resolve normally (with
> the ok property of the response set to false if the response isn’t in
> the range 200–299), and ***it will only reject on network failure or if
> anything prevented the request from completing***.

[Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

You should check the `response.ok` status.

```
const startHandler = () => {
  setOpenLoadingModal(true);
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: headers,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) { // <-- check response OK here
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(" ~ file: index.js ~ line 159 ~ .then ~ result", result)
      const { client_id, token } = result;
      if (!token || !client_id){
        setOpenErrorModal(true);
        return setOpenLoadingModal(false);
      } else{
        return history.push({
          pathname: FORMS_URL.LANDING_PAGE,
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)

      setOpenErrorModal(true);
      setOpenLoadingModal(false);
    });
};
```